# Unused argument nrows in subplot in plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

Few days ago, i was using subplot in plotly to plots multiple plots in one plots generated from plot_ly. Today, I am running the same code to proceed with my work but I am getting the following error.
Error in subplot(p3, p4, p5, nrows = 2) : unused argument (nrows = 2)

my p3, p4 and p5 have been defined in the following ways. I can load the individual plots.

```
p3 <- plot_ly(df_final, x = ~(1:length(index_3)), y = ~rmse_vec_mc[index_3], type = 'bar', name = 'rmse_3_mc', marker = list(color = 'yellowgreen')) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rmse_vec_ew[index_3], type = 'bar', name = 'rmse_3_ew', marker = list(color = 'steelblue4'))
```

But when i want to call `subplot(p3,p4,p5, nrows = 2)`, i get the following error.

Error in subplot(p3, p4, p5, nrows = 2) : unused argument (nrows = 2)

I looked up in the internet but couldn't find any related problems. If you have any idea, please share. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you have another package loaded with a function `subplot`? If so, then you may need to make sure you're using the one from `plotly` with `plotly:: subplot`.

Comment: thank you very much that saved my day :)

Comment: @Abdou. Thanks for the tip. Please write that as an answer so it can be upvoted and visible.